# R turn 6 digit number into HMS i.e. "130041" into "13:00:41"

Tags: r, time

As the question states, I want to turn "130041" into "13:00:41" i.e. HMS data

lubridate::ymd("20220413") works no problems but lubridate::hms("130041") does not.

I assume there should be a reasonably simply solution?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the output as a lubridate `Period` object, rather than a character vector, as you need to perform operations on it, you can use the approach suggested by Tim Biegeleisen of adding colon separators to the character vector and then using lubridate:

```r
x <- "130041"

gsub("(\\d{2})(?!$)", "\\1:", x, perl = TRUE) |> 
    lubridate::hms() 
# [1] "13H 0M 41S"
```

The output is similar but it is a Period object. I used a slightly different regex as well (add a colon when there are two digits not followed by the end of string) but it is fundamentally the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub` here:

```r
x <- "130041"
output <- sub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)
output

[1] "13:00:41"
```

Comment: Thank you! Gave the answer to SamR for the extra lubridate conversion, but this works all the same with a pipe into hms()

Comment: His regex is a bit sleaker than mine as well, you chose the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex which will will also work in case when hour uses only on digit.

```
gsub("(?=(..){1,2}$)", ":", c("130041", "30041"), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "13:00:41" "3:00:41"
```

Which can than be used in e.g. in `lubridate::hms` or `hms::as_hms`.

In `base::as.difftime` a format could be given: `as.difftime("130041", "%H%M%S")`